# Is Tensorflow's Help Really on SO?

Tags: discussion

I have been on SO for nearly six years now and have seen slight changes in position over time on this topic where we substitute Tensorflow for Tool X.  I know that many years ago anyway we did not like it when someone said go ask all your questions on SO.  Or at least sometimes, it was a delicate matter.

So for this particular tool, is what tensorflow says on its website the position of SO as well?  Is this a mutual agreement to have tensorflow's help on SO?

Comment: Some links and relevant text would be nice. [Here you go.](http://www.tensorflow.org/resources/index.html): "For help and support, technical or algorithmic questions, please submit your questions to Stack Overflow." And perhaps spelling "TensorFlow" as they prefer it as well. Still, I've seen worse.

Comment: Many projects and APIs ask users with questions about usage and debugging to go to Stack overflow. As long as questions are on-topic, I don't see an issue.

Comment: I wish they hadn't said "For help and support" as their opener there... They do note that discussions should occur on their mailing list, and support (install/compatibility) issues should go to their GitHub site. As long as it's programming related, it's cool.